# Don't Fragment flag in Java

Tags: java, udp

Is it possible in Java to send a UDP packet with the "Don't Fragment" flag set using the standard API?

I don't see any relevant options on [DatagramSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html) or [DatagramChannel.setOption](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/DatagramChannel.html#setOption(java.net.SocketOption,%20T)) (or better: [StandardSocketOptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/StandardSocketOptions.html)).

Answer (score 1):

The "Don't Fragment" flag is part of IP, not TCP or UDP.  IP is the protocol 1 layer below TCP and UDP (TCP and UDP packets are wrapped in IP).

You would need the ability to create a raw socket, which is not available in standard Java.  There seems to be a library called "RockSaw" which *might* be of use. Be aware that your program will need to have root/administrator permissions to access raw sockets.

Comment: Java does give me access to a couple of other layer 3 options like TOS, so I was hoping that maybe I had just missed the DF flag...