# Don't Fragment Flag in Java JDBC connection

Tags: java, sockets, jdbc, db2, mtu

The problem is when I use **JDBC** connection (usually with IBM DB2 driver) to a database through a path with low **MTU** size, I get **socket read timeout exception**!

I have set the **client's MTU much lower** than the path's MTU, but it is not working.

I have also dumped packets by wireshark and I found out that Don't Fragment Flag (**DF Flag**) is set. But when I create a **normal java socket**, it doesn't set this flag, and it works correctly.

How can I unset this DF flag in JDBC?

By the way, I have also check this question: [Don't Fragment flag in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41032248/dont-fragment-flag-in-java) and I think that cannot be the answer, because both jdbc also uses normal java socket, and DF flag is set in jdbc, but not set in normal java socket. **So it can be set somehow**.

Comment: JDBC itself is nothing more than a set of interface with implementation requirements. The implementation depends on the underlying JDBC driver implementation. It is unlikely that you have this problem with any JDBC connection, but probably only with a specific driver (or specific drivers), because the socket creation and configuration is part of the specific implementation of a JDBC driver; it is not part of JDBC itself. I'd suggest posting a [mre].

Comment: I would start by checking the documentation of your DB2 driver, and if that doesn't provide a solution, to contact IBM to ask for support.

Comment: I suspect the Db2 driver wants the MTU to match the network block size (so I would expect unpredictable results if you set the client MTU lower than the path MTU). If you have an easily reproducible scenario for which you can take the relevant jdbc trace (and wireshark trace) then IBM might advise you further if you have a paid support contract.